# как дополнительно отсортировать уже отсортированный массив php?

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Привет!
Есть массив, который отсортирован по значениям - от большего к меньшему. Как отсортировать его ещё и по ключам, чтобы ключи с одинаковыми значениями шли в алфавитном порядке? Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать для этого функцию **array_multisort**

Пример:

```
 <?php
    $array = [
        'tangerine' => 3,
        'plum' => 1,
        'apple' => 1
    ];

    array_multisort(array_values($array), SORT_DESC, array_keys($array), SORT_ASC, $array);
```

Результат:

```
array(3) {
  ["tangerine"]=>
  int(3)
  ["apple"]=>
  int(1)
  ["plum"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Сначала мы сортируем по значением массива, после чего сортируем по ключам и добавляем $array в качестве последнего параметра, для сортировки по общему ключу.

Comment: Супер! Спасибо огромное )